# How to made item.Value with DisplayFor() ?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm using default schema of Create View and in my model i've got a field that's a DateTime.

Now i'm doing that, cause if i use the @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BirthDate) i see a string formatted in this way 13/02/1989 00:00:00 instead of this 16/02/1989

First of All: How to make all with DisplayFor statement? And... How it Works with datatype, it's a good practice?
Next: I wonder i have some homework to do, some suggestion?

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr class="odd gradeX">
                            <td>
                                <input name="UserIDs" type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value=@item.Id />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName) 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fax)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.BirthDate.ToShortDateString()
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { Id = item.Id })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
```

Comment: `I wonder i have some homework to do, some suggestion?` Do your homework?!

Comment: Try preparing you view model field with [DataType] and [DisplayFormat] attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this using statement to your model:

`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

Then add this attribute to your BirthDate field:

`[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy'-'MM'-'dd}")]`

Edit as necessary.